# Regular Expressions: Match Nth Word

Tags: regex, notepad++

```
bla morebla evenmorebla
bla morebla evenmorebla
```

Using regex (for this instance I am using notepad++), how do I replace the first word in each line with, `[\command1{bla}]`, and the second word with, `\command2{morebla}`

Comment: Did you try your hand at it?

Comment: Yes, but minimalist knowledge barely helped with the first part. (And only for matching that is.)

Comment: It seems that you can only do it in Funduc S&R tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search regex:**

```
^(\w+) (\w+)
```

**Replace:**

```
[\command1$1] \command2$2
```

Comment: I could not get your answer work. Search matches the first two words but replace does not seem to work properly.

Comment: @blackened AFAIK there is no way to extract the number of the match. You'll have to create as many terms like this as there are words in the longest line

Comment: The result string with this pattern is not the same as OP's request. Plus, if there is more than one space between first and second word. This regex would fail.

Answer (score 1):

Open Notepad++ >> Replace. with 'Wrap acound' checked:

Search: `(\w+)\s+(\w+).*`

Replace with: `[\\command1{\1}] \\command2{\2}`

[The DEMO.](https://regex101.com/r/vC6hP9/1)

Comment: How do you modify your regex such that it will make replace the first and second word (as it does now) but will not affect the rest?

Comment: I may have lines with any number of words, and replace the first two as per your example, but without affecting the rest of the line (after the second word.)

Comment: Then check out [this one](https://regex101.com/r/vC6hP9/3). If it does not meet your needs, please provide a sample text.